# MonogoDB Aggregation Framework - How can I Include fields from the original document?

Tags: mongodb, grouping, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to Mongo and I'm trying to wrap my head around performing aggregations using the Aggregation Framework.

Suppose I have the following documents in a collection:

```
{name: "Sara", brandId: 1, count: 2 day:1/6/2014}//day value is ISODate
{name: "Sally", brandId: 1, count: 5 day:1/7/2014} 
{name: "Mike", brandId: 1, count: 2, day: 1/8/2014} 
{name: "Bob", brandId: 1, count: 4 day: 1/8/2014}
{name: "Joe", brandId: 1, count: 5 day:1/8/2014}
```

What I would like to do is create a report (project to a document) that looks like this:

Given date range: 1/7/2014 - 1/8/2014

```
{
    totalCount: 18,
    countForTimePeriod: 11,
    dailyAnalytics: [{
        count : 5,
        day: 7,
        month: 1,
        year: 2014
    },
    {
        count : 2,
        day: 8,
        month: 1,
        year: 2014
    },
    {
        count : 4,
        day: 8,
        month: 1,
        year: 2014
    },
    {
        count : 5,
        day: 8,
        month: 1,
        year: 2014
    }]
}
```

totalCount = aggregation of count from all documents, grouped by brandId
countForTimePeriod = aggregation of count within date range
dailyAnalytics = array of embedded documents containing counts for days with in date range. (I can figure out pulling out the date components.. I hope ;) )

I can't seem to find more than rudimentary examples of grouping and projecting.So far I am grouping the collection by 'day' and 'brandId'. I don't know how I would perform an aggregation that includes calculated values outside of my date rang i.e. totalCount & countForTimePeriod

I'm struggling to even begin. Can someone give me some direction?

```
db.brandCollection.aggregate({$group:{
        _id: {brandId: "$brandId", dayOfYear: "$day"},
        Count: {$sum: "$count"}
        }}
    );
```

Comment: I find this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/ to often be a useful guide.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Yes. The conversation chart is helpful. Thanks. I have been trying to get my desired output using a single aggregation pipeline. I'm beginning to think I may have to run more than one query to get my desired result. Is that true? My problems come about because I'm trying to get aggregate values that would need to be calculated before any grouping happens. i.e. totalCount for all "matching" documents outside of a date range.

Comment: You might want to see if you could do some of the other totaling based on the results of a single aggregation, on the client side.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I'll keep doing some trial and error. I'm new to mongo and the book I am reading must have been written before the aggregation framework was around because it makes no mention. doh! :)

Comment: @Nick do you still need help with this question? It looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028018/mongodb-how-can-i-use-multiple-groups-in-an-aggregation-pipeline, which you have figured out.